# How $F_n$ is related to $F_{n+1}$

Tags: probability

A researcher has computed the empirical distribution $F_n$ for a data set $x_1, x_2, . . . , x_n$. She discovers an extra data point, $x_{n+1}$. She wonders how $F_n$ is related to $F_{n+1}$, the empirical distribution function for the new data set. Which of the following statements is correct?

a) $F_{n+1}(x)=F_n(x)− \frac{1}{n+1}\:for\:−∞<x<∞$ 
b) $F_{n+1}(x)=F_n(x)+ \frac{1}{n+1}\:for\:−∞<x<∞$ 
c) $F_{n+1}(x_n) ≤ F_n(x_n)\:if\:x_n > x_{n+1}$ 
d) $F_{n+1}(x_2) ≤ F_n(x_2)\:if\:x_2 < x_{n+1}$ 
e) $F_{n+1}(x) = F_n(x)\:if\:x > x_{n+1}$ 
f) $F_{n+1}(x) = F_n(x)\:if\:x < x_{n+1}$

I have no clue how to find the correct answer (D) can someone help me?

Comment: The relation is $F_n+F_{n+1}=F_{n+2}$, if you ask Fibonacci:)

Comment: @DietrichBurde Nonsense.

Comment: Mark, use the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function

Comment: Ok I'll try thanks